# Why might rsyslog %syslogtag% display "(none)"?

Tags: linux, rsyslog, c++, rsyslogd

Given the following lines in an instance of `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$template MyFmt, "%timereported:::date-year%%timereported:::date-month%%timereported:::date-day%_%timereported:::date-hour%%timereported:::date-minute%%timereported:::date-second% %fromhost-ip% %fromhost% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%programname%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"

auth,authpriv.*                            |/path/to/log;MyFmt
```

Assume the syslog sender is a compiled C++ program, i.e. something like:

```
// main.cpp

#include <ctime>
#include <syslog.h>

int main( int argc, char* artv[] )
{
  openlog( "LogTest[456]", 0, LOG_AUTH );
  syslog( LOG_AUTH | LOG_INFO, "hello, world %zu", size_t( time( NULL ) ) );
  closelog();
  return 0;
}
```

Then why might an entry in `/var/log/secure` have its `%syslogtag%` and `%programname%` values "`(none)`" ? Does it necessarily mean the program would have called "`openlog( "(none)", ... );`" ?

I tried modifying the above program to pass `openlog()` first argument values `""` (empty string) and `NULL`. In case of the former, the resulting `%syslogtag%` value was an empty string, and in case of the latter, the resulting `%syslogtag%` value was "`a.out`", i.e. my executable's name. I can't think of what else might result in a value of "`(none)`" other than explicitly specifying so to `openlog()`...?

**Edit**: To be clear: the above example program *does not* result in a `%syslogtag%` value of "`(none)`" - it results in an expected value of "`LogTest[456]`". My question is more: what would cause a `%syslogtag%` value of "`(none)`", other than explicitly specifying so to `openlog()`?

(I'm trying to understand observed behavior at work: rsyslogd running on a server receives syslogs from clients and writes them in a templated format to a pipe, as above. *Some* of the written content has a `%syslogtag%` value of "`(none)`" - I'd like to understand potential reasons why.)